# Открыть файл в уже запущеном процессе по id (C#)

Tags: c#

Есть сторонняя программа которая каждый раз открывается в новом окне. То есть если запусть ее дважды - будет два процесса со своими ID. Если попробовать открыть файл ассоциированный с этой программой, то он откроется в том окне, которое было запущено первым. Можно ли на шарпе заставить файл открыться в конкретном окне программы.

Comment: Боюсь что это зависит от сторонней программы. Все эти манипуляции с перехватом приложений прописаны в ее коде. Соответственно, скорее всего универсального способа нет и нужно искать варианты запуска в документации конкретной сторонней программы.

Comment: очень мало конкретики....скорее всего можно как то (возможно придется не только на шарпе писать, либо юзать либы) но однозначный ответа дать сложно, т к задача имеет свою индивидуальность. И еще...`открыться в конкретном окне программы` - в вашей программы или в сторонней ?